# Byte array to Decimal

Tags: c, winapi

i have a byte array (64-bit unsigned integer) :

```
byte array[8] = { 0x01,0xc9,0x98,0x57,0xd1,0x47,0xf3,0x60 }
```

i want to translate it into decimal..
when i'am using the calculator windows the result is :

`128801567297500000`

i don't find a way to do it in winapi or C ..

Any help is appreciated.

for a 4 bytes array i use the working code below

```
BYTE array[4] = { 0xC3,0x02,0x00,0x00 };
printf("Result : %d\n",(array[0]) | (array[1]) <<8 |(array[2]) <<16 | (array[3]) <<24  );
Result : 707
```

Comment: your "working code" does not even compile.

Comment: this has nothing to do with winapi

Comment: how hard can it be to post working examples? This doesnt compile :
https://ideone.com/ZlCTyL

Comment: Your desired output and code sample for the smaller array don't agree on endianness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the bytes to 64bit before the shifting. Currently they are implicitly promoted to int, which is a 32bit data type.

Assuming you use stdint:

`uint64_t result = ((uint64_t)b[0]) | ((uint64_t)b[1] << 8) | ((uint64_t)b[2] << 16) | ((uint64_t)b[3] << 24) | ((uint64_t)b[4] << 32) | ((uint64_t)b[5] << 40) | ((uint64_t)b[6] << 48) | ((uint64_t)b[7] << 56);`

or in reverse order (array is little endian; this will get the result you're seeing in windows calculator):

`uint64_t result = ((uint64_t)b[7]) | ((uint64_t)b[6] << 8) | ((uint64_t)b[5] << 16) | ((uint64_t)b[4] << 24) |     ((uint64_t)b[3] << 32) | ((uint64_t)b[2] << 40) | ((uint64_t)b[1] << 48) | ((uint64_t)b[0] << 56);`

Answer (score 1):

well, you can use

1. `sprintf()` to print the positional hex values to a string.
2. convert that string to decimal using `strtoll()` using base 16.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 128

int main()
{
    char array[8] = { 0x01,0xc9,0x98,0x57,0xd1,0x47,0xf3,0x60 };

    char arr[SIZE] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    unsigned long long res = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        sprintf((arr + (i * 2)), "%2x", (array[i] & 0xff));

    printf("arr is %s\n", arr);

    res = strtoll(arr, NULL, 16);
    printf("res is %llu\n", res);

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Er, you really should not be using text for this at all

Answer (score 1):

```
int i;
byte array[8] = { 0x01,0xc9,0x98,0x57,0xd1,0x47,0xf3,0x60 };
unsigned long long v;

//Change of endian
for(i=0;i<4;++i){
    byte temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[7-i];
    array[7-i] = temp;
}
v = memcpy(&v, array, sizeof(v));//*(unsigned long long*)array;
printf("%llu ", v);
```

Comment: `v = *(unsigned long long*)array;` breaks the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: [htonll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/desktop/jj710199(v=vs.85).aspx)